# Combining two queries OR and LEFT Join - MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm having trouble with a MySQL query (I'm a newbie so go easy on me!). I have a website with TV shows and want to select episodes aired between two dates (no problem) based on two different actions (for a custom schedule). Basically, I want to show the episode if the user is either following (uses_follow_shows) or watching the show (user_watched) so I thought I would have something like below but that doesn't work. It works okay except for the fact that my results have the results of one query on one side and the results of the other one on the other side.

ie:

```
    name                  a1    name            a
    Mistresses (US)        2    Wilfred (US)    2
    Mistresses (US)        2    Dexter          2
```

This is my query:

How can I make it so all my name are in the same column ?

```
       SELECT * FROM (
         SELECT shows.name, users_follow_shows.user_id a1
       FROM show_episode_airdate join
            show_episode 
            on show_episode.episode_id = show_episode_airdate.episode_id join
            shows
            on shows.imdb_id = show_episode.imdb_id_show join
            show_network
            on show_network.show_id = shows.id join
            network
            on show_network.network_id = network.network_id join
            users_follow_shows
            on shows.id = users_follow_shows.show_id 

       WHERE show_episode_airdate.airdate BETWEEN '2013-07-20' AND '2013-07-27' and
             users_follow_shows.user_id = 2 

       ORDER by network.network_id ASC) a1

        JOIN (
         SELECT  shows.name, user_watched.user_id a
       FROM show_episode_airdate join
            show_episode 
            on show_episode.episode_id = show_episode_airdate.episode_id join
            shows
            on shows.imdb_id = show_episode.imdb_id_show join
            show_network
            on show_network.show_id = shows.id join
            network
            on show_network.network_id = network.network_id join
            user_watched
            on shows.id = user_watched.show_id 

       WHERE show_episode_airdate.airdate BETWEEN '2013-07-20' AND '2013-07-27' and
             user_watched.user_id = 2 

       ORDER by network.network_id ASC) a

       ON a = a1
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: In your query a and a1 are tables. You can't join on table = table, but have to specify fields to join on: ON a.field1 = a1.fieldN

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't use a JOIN. What You are looking for is a UNION:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html

Answer (score 1):

You can start with something like this subquery:

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id, show_id
  FROM (
     SELECT user_id
            show_id
       FROM user_watched
     UNION
     SELECT user_id
            show_id
       FROM user_follows_show
  )
```

This will give you a virtual table of unique users and shows that meets your two criteria for including them in your list.  You can then JOIN that into the rest of your query like so:

```
SELECT whatever
  FROM whatever
  JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT user_id, show_id
      FROM (
         SELECT user_id
                show_id
           FROM user_watched
         UNION
         SELECT user_id
                show_id
           FROM user_follows_show
      ) USER_INTERESTED ON USER_INTERESTED.show_id = shows.id
  WHERE whatever
```

The trick is to use the *Structured* part of *Structured Query Language* to get the virtual relationship between user / show you need for the request of your query.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but I would simplify your query like this:

```
SELECT 
    shows.name,
    users_follow_shows.user_id a1
FROM show_episode_airdate
    JOIN show_episode on show_episode.episode_id = show_episode_airdate.episode_id
    JOIN shows on shows.imdb_id = show_episode.imdb_id_show
    JOIN show_network on show_network.show_id = shows.id
    JOIN network on show_network.network_id = network.network_id
    LEFT JOIN users_follow_shows on shows.id = users_follow_shows.show_id
    LEFT JOIN user_watched on shows.id = user_watched.show_id
WHERE show_episode_airdate.airdate BETWEEN '2013-07-20' AND '2013-07-27'
    AND (users_follow_shows.user_id = 2 OR user_watched.user_id = 2)
```